# Shiny: Why did the lubridate::today() function suddenly start returning a past date in a production deployment?

Tags: r, shiny, lubridate

We use the today() function to set the upper limit for a date selection input in a shiny dashboard.

```
        dateRangeInput(inputId = ns("transactionDateRange"),
                       label = "Date Range",
                       max =  today(),
                       start = today() - 28,
                       end =  today())
      ),
```

Today (Monday) I opened the dashboard in RStudio connect in our production environment and the upper limit ("max") is set at the date of last Thursday. The "start" parameter is also returning 28 days before last Thursday. Why would this happen one day when it wasn't a problem the previous day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a strange behaviour... The [`lubridate::today()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/now.html) function does nothing special but calls [`Sys.time()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.time.html) from base R and formats it as date in the specified timezone. See the current [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/blob/master/R/instants.r).

And `Sys.time()`'s [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.time.html) says:

> Sys.time and Sys.Date returns the system's idea of the current date with and without time.

So I think at the first place there can be some problem with your production environment's date and time. Try to check that in the terminal or R console.

(I don't think it's very likely that the date and time would be cached.)

Other possible scenarios:

- your browser remembers the last selection in the input - try to open your app from another computer,
- the app could intentionally save some cookies/settings (however in my opinion Shiny should not do this by default, so check your app's code or try that from another computer).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas Petr. I'll let you know if anything works.

Comment: It turns out another dashboard hosted on the same server is having the same issue, so probably a problem with the environment's date and time as you suggested.